# Load web with custom referer java

Tags: java, netbeans, webview, javafx

i have a java application and i need load a webpage in a panel, but i need load it with a custom referrer. My web take this referrer and save it. Is very important to be in the referer header. To load webpage i'm use JavaFX but this not have a function to change 'Referer' header, only have a function to change 'User-Agent':

```
webEngine.setUserAgent("new user-agent");
```

but i not need it.

Please help me! Thank